# Represent Nondeterministic Finite State Machine Simulator in Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, monads

I am following "programming languages" on Udacity and trying to represent the problem sets in Haskell. The answers are written in Python:

```
edges = {(1,"a") : [2,3]
        ,(2,"a") : [2]
        ,(3,"b") : [3,4]
        ,(4,"c") : [5]}

accepting = [2,5]

def nfsmSim(string, current, edges, accepting):
    if string == "":
        return current in accepting
    else:
        letter = string[0]
        key = (current, letter)
        if key in edges:
            rest = string[1:]
            states = edges[key]
            for state in states:
                if nfsmSim(rest, state, edges, accepting):
                    return True
         return False
```

The starting state is always the first state i.e. `current = 1`.

Strings such as `"aaa"` or `"abc"` are accepted whilst `"abb"` or `"aabc"` or rejected.

My attempt at rewriting using Haskell:

```
nfsmSim [] c _  = [c]
nfsmSim xs c es = [concat $ nfsmSim (tail xs) s es | (k,ss) <- es, s <- ss, x <- xs, k==(c,x)]
```

I want to return a list of integers which represent the last state at the end of the input string and then `filter` these against the accepting states and use `any` to get a final `True` or `False`.

I realise this is not probably the Haskell way to do this and that there is probably a better `wholemeal` solution. However as a beginner I am struggling with mondadic mechanism and most likely the recursive nature of this problem.

Please point me in the right direction possibly using the `do` notation rather than the list comprehension.

Comment: Could you add a link to the exercise, if possible?

Comment: @Zeta [programming languages](https://www.udacity.com/course/programming-languages--cs262)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us think about the type first. Your Python function has the following type, more or less:

```hs
type State   = Int
type Map k v = [(k,v)]

nfsmSim :: String -> State -> Map (Int, Char) [State] -> [State] -> Bool
nfsmSim string current edges accepting = …
```

We can use pattern matching for the empty string case:

```hs
nfsmSim :: String -> State -> Map (Int, Char) [State] -> [State] -> Bool
nfsmSim "" current _ accepting = current `elem` accepting
```

For the non-empty case, we do the same as your Python code:

```hs
nfsmSim (x:xs) current edges accepting =
    let rest   = xs
        states = [s | (k,v) <- edges, k == (current,x), s <- v]
    in or [nfsmSim rest state edges accepting | state <- states]
```

However, that's not really easy to work with. Instead, let us write `nfsmSim` as higher order function and change the order of arguments:

```hs
nfsmSim :: (State -> Char -> [State])
        -> (State -> Bool)
        -> String
        -> State
        -> Bool
```

Now, instead of a list of edges, we have to provide a function that returns a (possible empty) list of states for a given state and character, and instead of a list of accepting states, we provide a function that returns `True` on those states.

For the empty string case, not too much changes:

```hs
nfsmSim advance accept "" current = accept current
```

We simply use our `State -> Bool` to check whether our current state is acceptable.

However, now that our `State` is the last parameter of `nfsmSim`, we can use currying to use your `any` approach:

```hs
nfsmSim advance accept (x:xs) current = 
    any (nfsmSim advance accept xs) (advance current x)
```

Note that it's kind of clunky to carry all arguments along. You would usually write a worker for that:

```hs
nfsmSim :: (a -> b -> [a]) -> (a -> Bool) -> [b] -> a -> Bool
nfsmSim advance accept string current = go string current
  where
    go []     c = accept c
    go (x:xs) c = any (go xs) (advance c x)
```

By the way, you can still use "edges" and "accepting" with the last variant,

```hs
nfsmSimAccept string current edges accepting =
   let accept  c   = c `elem` accepting
       advance c x = [s | (k,v) <- edges, k == (c,x), s <- v]
   in nfsmSim advance accept string current
```

which shows that the higher order function is more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for your solution(s). You've pitched the answer just right at my lowly ability and I've learnt a lot from your data approach. BTW when I copied your first solution and ran it in my haskell repl I got `Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'; Expected type: [State];Actual type: [Integer]`. I replaced `Int` by `Integer` everywhere and it compiled. Any reason why?

Comment: @potong Did you use an `Integer` somewhere?

Comment: I copied the solution as is. Perhaps the version (7.6.3) of Haskell has something to do with it? The final solution also objected until I replaced `b` with `Char`. I realise that type system is there to help and clarify my mudded thinking but sometimes it seems to be a little obtuse in its error messages. I guess I must study the messages more deeply  or perhaps there is a switch that can give a more verbose explanation?

Comment: @potong hm. That's out of scope of this question, but could you post your complete code as a gist or pastebin or similar? Without your surrounding code, it's hard to see where the error might be.

Comment: With a bit of tinkering I realised I had included `edges` and `accepting` in the compiled code without providing a type for either. I believe the compiler assigned `Integer` to both. By specifiying a type up front for both the problem went away. Thank  you for your patience, everyday I'm learning to think a little slower but clearer.

Comment: @potong: Hurr durr. Of course you had to replace `b` with `Char` if I use `""` for the empty list. After all, `""` is an `String`, not a `[a]`. Fixed that one. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as I know, no such thing as "Non Finite State Machine". Judging from what you wrote, I realized that it is about "Nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA)".

First variant.

```
nfa :: String -> Int -> [((Int, Char), [Int])] -> [Int] -> Bool
nfa       [] cur     _ acc = cur `elem` acc
nfa (c:rest) cur edges acc
    | Just states <- lookup (cur, c) edges = any (\state -> nfa rest state edges acc) states
    | otherwise                            = False

edges =
    [ ((1, 'a'), [2, 3])
    , ((2, 'a'), [2])
    , ((3, 'b'), [3, 4])
    , ((4, 'c'), [5])
    ]

accepting = [2, 5]

main = do
    print $ nfa "aaa" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa "abc" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa "abb" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa "aabc" 1 edges accepting
```

Output will be:

```
True
True
False
False
```

Second variant:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

nfa2 :: String -> Int -> [((Int, Char), [Int])] -> [Int] -> [Int]
nfa2       [] cur     _ acc = guard (cur `elem` acc) >> return cur
nfa2 (c:rest) cur edges acc = do
    state <- fromMaybe mzero $ lookup (cur, c) edges
    nfa2 rest state edges acc

edges =
    [ ((1, 'a'), [2, 3])
    , ((2, 'a'), [2])
    , ((3, 'b'), [3, 4])
    , ((4, 'c'), [5])
    ]

accepting = [2, 5]

main = do
    print $ nfa2 "aaa" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa2 "abc" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa2 "abb" 1 edges accepting
    print $ nfa2 "aabc" 1 edges accepting
```

Output will be:

```
[2]
[5]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my sloppy question! I've edited the title. Am I right in thinking `Just states <- lookup (cur, c) edges` is monadic? but with no `do` or `return`?

Comment: No, it's just Haskell 2010 syntax "Patter guard" (https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my Haskell-ish method:

We can use haskell's Data.Set and Data.Map libraries to represent our state machine.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Set as S
```

Let's define some datatypes for our state machine:

```
type State = Int
type Edge = (State, Char)
type Machine = (M.Map Edge (S.Set State), S.Set State)
```

We define the machine thusly:

```
myMachine :: Machine
myMachine = (M.fromList
    [ ((1, 'a'), S.fromList [2, 3])
    , ((2, 'a'), S.fromList [2   ])
    , ((3, 'b'), S.fromList [3, 4])
    , ((4, 'c'), S.fromList [5   ])
    ] , S.fromList [2, 5])
```

we can run the machine like this:

```
runMachine :: String -> Machine -> State -> Bool
runMachine "" (_, acceptingStates) currentState =
    S.member currentState acceptingStates
runMachine (ch:rest) machine@(edges, _) currentState =
    case M.lookup (currentState, ch) edges of
        Nothing -> False
        Just nextStates ->
            or $ S.map (runMachine rest machine) nextStates
```

Since the function returns a `Bool`, there is no great reason to use a monad or do-notation. However such a solution is possible if we use the type `Maybe ()` in place of `Bool`, where `Just ()` represents `True` and `Nothing` represents `False`.

Comment: The `Set` is an overkill. There's no need for the "end" states to be in a sorted set.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm at a low level of Haskell understanding, so many of the concepts you introduce will hopefully make more sense further down the line.